# Ionic Cordova Health Plugin - Not working on Ionic DevApp

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, healthkit, google-fit

I installed this plugin on my Ionic app: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/health/

This plugin is compatible with both Apple Health-Kit and Google-Fit. Here is my code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Health } from '@ionic-native/health';

@IonicPage({
  priority: 'off'
})
@Component({
  selector: 'page-health',
  templateUrl: 'health.html'
})

export class HealthPage {

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
          private health: Health) {

  this.health.isAvailable()
    .then((available:boolean) => {
    console.log(available);
    this.health.requestAuthorization([
      'distance', 'nutrition',  //read and write permissions
      {
        read: ['steps'],       //read only permission
        write: ['height', 'weight']  //write only permission
      }])
    .then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(e => console.log(e));
  })
    .catch(e => console.log(e));
  }
}
```

When I run it on DevApp I get these warnings (even though I installed the cordova and npm plugin):

> console.warn: Ionic Native: tried calling Health.isAvailable, but the Health plugin is not installed.
>
> console.warn: Install the Health plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-health'

I ran it using Xcode on my device and it's working properly. But what I want to do is to try it using Ionic DevApp because it's fast for editing and development. I checked and this plugin IS supported by the DevApp, so there should be no problem. See the link: https://ionicframework.com/docs/pro/devapp/

Any thoughts? Thank you!